# How to add a file from a branch to another branch in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging, mercurial-extension

I have two branches at my local repository: `default` and `s1`.

At `default` branch there is a file called `def.txt`, among others. The `s1` branch has files named as `set3.txt`, `set1.txt`, etc. I would like to add `set1.txt` of `s1` branch to `default` branch as well.

I have tried to use `hg add set1.txt` command when the working directory is at `default` branch. However, because `default` branch does not has the file, I cannot add it and it always gives me a error message such as `"no set1.txt file found"`.

I do not want to use `merge` command because I do not want to merge all other files from `s1` branch to `default` branch. I only want to add one file, `set1.txt`. I have tried `hg transplant -b s1`, too, but it seems not serving the same purpose.

So any idea how to work around this? My goal it to have these two branches look as below:

- `default`: `def.txt`, `set1.txt` etc.
- `s1`: `set1.txt`, `set3.txt` etc.

My machine is Red Hat Linux Workstation 6 which has Mercurial 1.7.3 and TortoiseHG 1.5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mercurial: Merging one file between branches in one repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078881/mercurial-merging-one-file-between-branches-in-one-repo)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a trick: "revert" the file `set1.txt` to the branch `s1`. Since branches are revisions, this will work:

```
$ hg revert -r s1 set1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`hg revert` is a cute trick.  I'd be more inclined to use `hg cat -r s1 set1.txt > set1.txt` however, that more explicitly does what you'd expect.  I don't think ultimately there's any difference between the two commands.

Intuitively, you're trying to merge a single file from one branch into your current branch.  A quick google turned up this article exploring this concept in a DVCS: http://josefbetancourt.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/merge-single-file-hg/

Comment: The `hg revert` hack has the advantage of preserving the history of the file. If you do `hg log set1.txt` on `default` branch it will show all previous commits. This is not as killer as some people find but it can be useful.